# How can I insert fields into the mysql database but skip a column or two if it's a duplicate?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm reading line by line from a file then inserting the details in a mysql database. But the issue is that some lines do not contain a field I called natted ip and port. I loop through the file then insert into db. However the issue is that because not every row contains natted ip and port, I need the database to skip these two columns when inserting into the table where they do not appear but insert the rest and not duplicate. How can I ensure that?

````
    public static void readData() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

        File fileName = new File(FILE);

        try(Scanner input = new Scanner(fileName) ){

            String firstLine, secondLine, thirdLine;
            firstLine = input.nextLine();


            secondLine = input.nextLine();
            String[] secondString = secondLine.split(" ");

            for(String string: secondString){

                timestamp = secondString[0]+" "+secondString[1];  //to be inserted
                timezone =  secondString[2]; //to be inserted
            }


            thirdLine = input.nextLine();
            String[] thirdString = thirdLine.split(":");

            for(String string: thirdString){

                session = thirdString[1].trim();  //to be inserted
            }



            while(input.hasNextLine()){

                String line;
                line = input.nextLine();

                String[] cdr_string = line.split(" ");

                for(String string:cdr_string){
                    type = cdr_string[1].trim(); //to be inserted
                    internalIP_and_port = cdr_string[8];
                    destinationIP_and_port = cdr_string[10].trim();    
                }

                if(internalIP_and_port.contains("[")){
                    String[] splitIPs = internalIP_and_port.split(Pattern.quote("["));

                    for(String string:splitIPs){
                        internalIP_and_port = splitIPs[0].trim();
                        nattedIP_and_port = splitIPs[1].trim();
                        nattedIP_and_port = nattedIP_and_port.substring(0, nattedIP_and_port.length() -1);
                    }

                    String[] splitIP_and_port = nattedIP_and_port.split(":");

                    for(String string:splitIP_and_port){
                        natted_ip = splitIP_and_port[0].trim();  //to be inserted
                        natted_port = splitIP_and_port[1].trim();  //to be inserted
                    }
//                    System.out.println(natted_ip);
                }

                String[] split_internal_IP_and_port = internalIP_and_port.split(":");

                for(String string : split_internal_IP_and_port){
                    internal_ip = split_internal_IP_and_port[0].trim(); //to be inserted
                    internal_port = split_internal_IP_and_port[1].trim();  //to be inserted
                }

                String[] split_destination_IP_and_port = destinationIP_and_port.split(":");

                for(String string : split_destination_IP_and_port){
                    destination_ip = split_destination_IP_and_port[0].trim(); //to be inserted
                    destination_port = split_destination_IP_and_port[1].trim(); //to be inserted
                }

                saveData();

            }

        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

        File log_done = new File(FILE_DONE);
        fileName.renameTo(log_done);
        fileName.delete();
    }

    private static void saveData() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

        Connection con = connect();

        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO decoder(type, internal_ip, internal_port, natted_ip, natted_port, destination_ip, destination_port, session, timestamp, timezone, filename) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

        stmt.setString(1, type);
        stmt.setString(2, internal_ip);
        stmt.setString(3, internal_port);
        stmt.setString(4, natted_ip);
        stmt.setString(5, natted_port);
        stmt.setString(6, destination_ip);
        stmt.setString(7, destination_port);
        stmt.setString(8, session);
        stmt.setString(9, timestamp);
        stmt.setString(10, timezone);
        stmt.setString(11, FILENAME);

        stmt.executeUpdate();

    }
    public static Connection connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    }```

I'm reading from this file:
 udp  VPN: public --> public  41.72.118.178:56620 --> 103.10.116.19:51130
 https  VPN: public --> public  10.65.19.224:46765[165.56.53.149:15674] --> 31.13.75.36:443
 tcp  VPN: public --> public  35.212.240.3:34533 --> 41.72.96.58:20792
 dns  VPN: public --> public  10.65.179.189:12718 --> 165.56.45.2:53
 https  VPN: public --> public  10.65.145.37:34490[165.56.53.161:38013] --> 185.60.219.9:443
 https  VPN: public --> public  10.65.14.63:43956[165.56.53.178:27552] --> 216.58.223.106:443
 https  VPN: public --> public  10.66.32.44:37573[165.56.53.141:29821] --> 185.60.219.33:443
 udp  VPN: public --> public  172.21.242.243:10188[41.72.123.88:55777] --> 119.3.74.66:10327
 http  VPN: public --> public  172.21.218.82:65167[41.72.121.132:46765] --> 5.45.58.214:80
 https  VPN: public --> public  10.66.118.81:52792[165.56.53.185:46319] --> 104.82.200.59:443
 udp  VPN: public --> public  76.64.76.78:13114 --> 41.72.108.238:34835

I want it to show like this:
+----+----------+----------------+---------------+---------------+------------
| id | type     | internal_ip    | internal_port | natted_ip     | natted_port  
+----+----------+----------------+---------------+---------------+------------
|  1 | udp      | 41.72.118.178  | 56620         | NULL          | NULL        |  
|  2 | https    | 10.65.19.224   | 46765         | 165.56.53.149 | 15674       |  
|  3 | tcp      | 35.212.240.3   | 34533         | NULL      | NULL        |  
|  4 | dns      | 10.65.179.189  | 12718         | NULL      | NULL        |  
|  5 | https    | 10.65.145.37   | 34490         | 165.56.53.161 | 38013       |  
|  6 | https    | 10.65.14.63    | 43956         | 165.56.53.178 | 27552       |  
|  7 | https    | 10.66.32.44    | 37573         | 165.56.53.141 | 29821       |  
|  8 | udp      | 172.21.242.243 | 10188         | 41.72.123.88  | 55777       |  
|  9 | http     | 172.21.218.82  | 65167         | 41.72.121.132 | 46765       |  
| 10 | https    | 10.66.118.81   | 52792         | 165.56.53.185 | NULL        |  
| 11 | udp      | 76.64.76.78    | 13114         | NULL      | NULL        |  
| 12 | https    | 10.66.81.19    | 34736         | 165.56.53.81  | 29021       |  
| 13 | tcp      | 10.66.18.62    | 55976         | 165.56.53.233 | 62585 


And not like this:

+----+----------+----------------+---------------+---------------+------------
| id | type     | internal_ip    | internal_port | natted_ip     | natted_port  
+----+----------+----------------+---------------+---------------+------------
|  1 | udp      | 41.72.118.178  | 56620         | NULL          | NULL        |  
|  2 | https    | 10.65.19.224   | 46765         | 165.56.53.149 | 15674       |  
|  3 | tcp      | 35.212.240.3   | 34533         | 165.56.53.149 | 15674       |  
|  4 | dns      | 10.65.179.189  | 12718         | 165.56.53.149 | 15674       |  
|  5 | https    | 10.65.145.37   | 34490         | 165.56.53.161 | 38013       |  
|  6 | https    | 10.65.14.63    | 43956         | 165.56.53.178 | 27552       |  
|  7 | https    | 10.66.32.44    | 37573         | 165.56.53.141 | 29821       |  
|  8 | udp      | 172.21.242.243 | 10188         | 41.72.123.88  | 55777
````

Answer (score 0):

you should initialize natted_ip and natted_port outside of for like below code.
because this variables save data from previous record and you don't clear them. it can be happen for all variables that can be null.

```
natted_ip = null;
natted_port = null;
for(String string:splitIP_and_port){
       natted_ip = splitIP_and_port[0].trim();  
       natted_port = splitIP_and_port[1].trim();  
}
```